# What would be “Sternum-Intermediate” distance?

Tags: human-anatomy, definitions, bone-biology

I've asked [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/303268/what-would-be-sternum-intermediate-distance) on the *English Language & Usage* board, not being entirely sure whether this question is strictly medical, or just English knowledge suffices to answer.

Do note I am no native speaker, hence I am afraid to misinterpret the possibly obvious thing.

In an [article](http://www.depthbiomechanics.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/downloads/2012/10/EFL-report.pdf) written by Wheat et al Engineernig for Life - Kinect Report the authors use the scanning device to calcuate distances on the human body.

The measured distances are: Sternum-Intermediate, Inter-nipple and Sternum-nipple (see Table 3.). The latter two are obvious. The first one, however, not so much. Unfortunately, the authors do not provide a definition, probably assuming it is clear to the reader.

What would be the Sternum-Intermediate? Is this the sternum's length or is "Intermediate" some specific body part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article states:

> Markers (blue stickers, approximately 1 cm in diameter) were attached
>   to a point approximating the suprasternal notch and **an intermediate
>   position on the dorsal aspect of the left breast**. The position of
>   these markers and the two nipples of the model were extracted from the
>   point cloud scan of the breast model through manual digitising using
>   Meshlab...Three straight line distances were analysed (1. internipple,
>   2. sternum-to-right nipple and 3. sternum-to-intermediate marker).

One can infer that the sternum-intermediate distance is from the sternum to the intermediate marker on the dorsal aspect of the left breast. It is not, I believe, a widely measured anatomical distance, rather one 'invented' for the purposes of the study.